# Solving an equation involving rearrangements of a 3 digit number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Bob has `S` amount of money where `100 <= S <= 999` i.e it is a three-digit number. Bob spends some amount for buying lunch which is a rearrangement of the digits of `S`. Also, the leftover money he has is also a rearrangement of the digits of `S`. What is the value of `S`?

I tried to solve it by fixing $S = 100x + 10y + z$, where *x*, *y* and *z* are the three digits of `S`.
So, the required equation would be something like:
$100x + 10y + z - (100y + 10z + x) = 100z + 10x + y$.
But I can't proceed as there can be different arrangements of digits among the rearranged numbers and hence there could be many possibilities.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, first note that any rearrangement leaves the number unchanged $\pmod 9$ and, since the difference of two such must be $0\pmod 9$, the original number must be a multiple of $9$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do this by reasoning and trial and error. If the number is $100x+10y+z$, let the number subtracted be $100y+10z+x$. 
Case 1: if the resulting term is $100x+10z+y$, then $y=0$, $100-th$ place will be $x-1$, $10-th$ place is $10-z$, unit place is $z-x$, and one of them mujst be $0$, clearly $10-th$ place cannot be, so take subcases:
Subcase 1: $x=1$. This is not possible as one of the digits in the answer must be $1$, and clearly, that will be a unit digit. Then we get $z=2$. The $10-th$ digit then gives the value $8$, but you cannot satisfy the given condition. 
Subcase 2: $z=x$. In the process of satisfying the given condition, we will notice that $100-th$ digit is not positive. This is also not possible. 
Similarly proceed for other cases. 
Now, let the subtracted number be $100x+10z+y$. 
$100-th$ digit (in the answer) is $0$ (so we keep in mind one of the digits must be $0$, clearly not $x$). Note that $y\neq 0$ since otherwise $10-th$ digit in teh answer will be $-z$, not possible (also both $y$ and $z$ cannot be $0$ together). 
So, take $z=0$, then in the final answer, $10-th$ digit=$y-1$ and unit digit = $10-y$. Suppose $y-1=x$ and $10-y=y$ (from the given condition), then we have $x=4$ and $y=5$. Thus the initial number is $450$, $405$ got subtracted to give you $045$. 
(Although this seems very long, some cases could be directly removed).

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful!